# Git for legacy symfony 1.4 project

Tags: git, workflow, symfony-1.4

I have legacy symfony 1.4 projects.

And sometimes need to fix something in code with freelance coders.

What is the best way to track changes in git, and don't share full code of project?

I know about git submodules, but don't know how to divide the app.

How I should organize submodules?

- Each app/module or
- Each app

And what about lib folder?

Is it possible to have structure of git repo, which allow share to developer only one (or several) modules without full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A submodule is basically a git repo that someone can use in their project. So if you want to make each module a submodule you should put each module in a separate repository. And I think this is a solution which should suit your needs. You can give access to the repos to developers you want to work with. In each repo you can define the submodules which are needed to test and develop the module (e.g. submodule with sf, submodule with the model definition, etc.)

If your application can be easily divided into separate chunks (each chunk having its' own model, controller and view) you can move your code to plugins and put each plugin in separate repository. This way a developer will have everything he/she needs to work with the piece of code.

Comment: I have problem with plugin. I have some tables wich have relations to all other modules.